# Mockito complains about wrong arguments

Tags: java, testing, mockito, verify

We try to verify the behaviour of an action with Mockito. The test code looks like this

```
final Type1 mock = mock(Type1.class);
new SomeAction<Type1>(mock).actionPerformed(null);

verify(mock).someMethod();
```

The method actionPerformed contains just the call of someMethod on the object provided in the constructor of Type1. Yet Mockito complains that the expected method call did not happen, instead a different method call happened. But the String representation of the two calls printed by Mockito are exactly the same!

Any explanation what is going on?

Update: ErrorMessage from Mockito

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
type1.someMethod();
-> at xxx
Actual invocation has different arguments:
type1.someMethod();
-> at xxx
```

Comment: I tried this out, and it worked as you expect it should work (verify passes.) What version of Mockito are you using? I am on 1.8. Are you sure your null parameter isn't causing a different branch to be taken?

Comment: Version is 1.8.5; someMethod is a oneliner, so there really isn't a different part.

Comment: Could you provide a SSCCE please?

Comment: Just tried it out with version 1.8.5 and this all passes. Something you are doing must be different.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have arguments to those methods? Arguments with the same string representation?

Comment: someMethod has no arguments and is of type void ... but Type1 actually has a type parameter ... does that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a stretch, but check your toString implementations. I've ran into some irritating unit test scenarios where the expected and observed appeared to be the same from the unit test point of view when in reality they were different. In the end it was a variation in toString that caused me to believe there was a similarity when in reality there was not.

Comment: since the method returns void and doesn't take arguments there isn't any toString involved ... I think.

Comment: The toString() representation showed in the unit test result tricked me once. To figure out if the 2 objects Mockito was complaining about are or not different, I overridden the toString again as it is in Object.